# How to input int, vector of int, int and vector of string correctly

Tags: c++, vector, input

I try to input 2 numbers (int) and 2 vectors (int, string):

```
   int N_num;
   int N_dir;
   vector<int> v;
   vector<string> v1;
   std::cin >> N_num;
   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
       std::istream_iterator<int>(),std::back_inserter(v));
   std::cin >> N_dir;
   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<string>(std::cin),
       std::istream_iterator<string>(), std::back_inserter(v1));
```

My input is:

```
3
1 4 5
4
T M M R
```

Then I cout N_dir (= 4), and get -858993460 as an output. My guess is that the first vector input does not terminate when I input "4" to N_dir. How do I stop inputting a vector and go to the next variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first `std::copy` call will read the `4` that is supposed to be read into `N_dir`. So when you attempt to read into `N_dir` you read the first string instead and the input operation will fail and not initialize `N_dir`, leaving it indeterminate.

Use [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) instead:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), N_num,
            std::back_inserter(v));
```